# How to compute latitude and longitude of a point at a distance from another point in some direction?

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude, bearing

I have the coordinates of a point on Earth and I want to know the coordinates of a point that is at a distance in meters from the first point in an angle in degrees from the north but I haven't found the way to do it.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 6):

The Java package [net.sf.geographiclib](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/java/) has this capability.  It uses the method described in my paper [Algorithms for geodesics](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00190-012-0578-z).  Look at the documentation on [Direct(double lat1, double lon1, double azi1, double s12)](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/java/net/sf/geographiclib/Geodesic.html#Direct-double-double-double-double-).  Here's a sample of its use:

```
import java.util.*;
import net.sf.geographiclib.*;
public class Direct {
/**
 * Solve the direct geodesic problem.
 *
 * This program reads in lines with lat1, lon1, azi1, s12 and prints out
 * lines with lat2, lon2, azi2 (for the WGS84 ellipsoid).
 **********************************************************************/
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      double lat1, lon1, azi1, s12;
      while (true) {
        lat1 = in.nextDouble(); lon1 = in.nextDouble();
        azi1 = in.nextDouble(); s12 = in.nextDouble();
        GeodesicData g = Geodesic.WGS84.Direct(lat1, lon1, azi1, s12);
        System.out.println(g.lat2 + " " + g.lon2 + " " + g.azi2);
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the [Vincenty's formulae direct problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty's_formulae#Direct_Problem), i.e. given an initial point, its azimuth and a geodesic distance calculate the final point. For instance, there's a Python implementation of the direct problem available in the PyGeodesy package.

Example:

```
>>> from pygeodesy.ellipsoidalVincenty import LatLon 
>>> p = LatLon(-37.95103, 144.42487)
>>> d = p.destination(54972.271, 306.86816)
>>> print d.lon, d.lat
143.926497668 -37.6528177174
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to do it in an Android app. Do you know if there is a Java library that has a function like that?

Comment: It seems that @cffk has a Java working solution [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/241150/22405)