# Euclidean Coordinates to Lat Long Based on Reference Location in Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, coordinates, pyproj

### Goal

Convert Euclidean Coordinates to Latitude and Longitude given the Latitude and Longitude of euclidean origin using Python. To give a sense of scale and accuracy for my application, the coordinates will always be within 2,000 meters of the origin.

#### Data on hand.

```py
#A 'Anker Point' or the earth location for the cartesian origin (0,0)
euclidean_anker_point = [37.326695, -121.902583]

#The list of points to convert to lat lon
euclidean_points = [[1450.3, 400.8],[1460.2, 460.6],[1470.2, 470.2]]
```

The euclidean points currently have no projection system, have the units of Meters, and are only understood in euclidian space relative to the Anker point. I have no projection system for these coordinates.

#### First Pass

The below code does not provide accurate results but does seem to be in the ballpark. I believe how the bearing is calculated is not correct given my context.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to improve this approach?

```py
import numpy
import math
from pygeodesy.ellipsoidalVincenty import LatLon 

#create pygeodesy anker point
origin_point = LatLon(euclidean_anker_point[0], euclidean_anker_point[1])

#create ouput array
geographic_points = []

#for each point to convert to lat lon
for index, point in enumerate(euclidean_points):

    #get distance from anker point using Pythagorean theorem
    dist = math.sqrt((point[0]*point[0])+(point[1]*point[1])) 

    #get bearing using function (see below) 
    bearing = get_bearing(0,0,point[0],point[1])

    #use pygeodesy to calculate desination lat lon
    dest = origin_point.destination(dist, bearing)

    #add lat lon version of point to output array
    geographic_points.append([dest.lon,dest.lat])


def get_bearing(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):
    dLon = (long2 - long1)
    x = math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(math.radians(dLon))
    y = math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) * math.sin(math.radians(lat2)) - 
    math.sin(math.radians(lat1)) * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * 
    math.cos(math.radians(dLon))
    brng = numpy.arctan2(x,y)

    return brng
```

##### Credits

I am trying the [pygeodesy approach listed by Antonia Falciano](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241105/how-to-compute-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-point-at-a-distance-from-another-poin)
and using [Get_Bearing from Aliff Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54873868/python-calculate-bearing-between-two-lat-long)

Comment: Not criticising, just wondering why you want to roll your own reprojection code instead of using something like pyproj?

Comment: I would be happy to use pyproj or any other library that can do this out of the box. I will research pyproj but am currently unaware of how that would be done. I would certainly see any library-based implementation as a valid solution to this question.

Comment: I realize that my question is missing some key information and that I have mixed up some terminology. My points are Euclidean, not Cartesian. That is to say, I don't have a projection system for the points, only their relative location to the anker point. I will edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have gone with.

### Brief

The fastest way to deal with projections is using one of the many robust projection libraries out there. Most of these expect that your original coordinates have a projection system, so the best thing to do is to focus on converting the Euclidean points to Cartesian points, then re-project those into Latitude and Longitude.

### Step 1

Get the anker_point into a projection system with units that match your coordiante units.

```py
#A 'Anker Point' or the earth location for the cartesian origin (0,0)
anker_point = [37.326695, -121.902583]

#Cartesian Projection System
inProj = Proj(init='epsg:2227')

#Anker Projection System
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')

#using the pyproj library (thanks user2856!)
from pyproj import Proj, transform

#produce a anker point with same units as euclidean points
cartesian_anker_point= transform(outProj,inProj,anker_point[1],anker_point [0])
```

### Step 2

Now we can use the cartesian anker point to locate the Euclidean coordinates in our cartesian space.

```py
#euclidian point to locate
euclidan_point = [1450.3, 400.8]

#located point in  inProj system
cartisan_point = [euclidan_point[0]+cartesian_anker_point[0],euclidan_point[1]+cartesian_anker_point[1]]
```

### Step 3

With a located Cartesian point we can now project to lat lon

```py
#located point in  outProj system
latLon_Point = transform(inProj,outProj,cartisan_point[0],cartisan_point [1])
```